# Remove two or more words in a cell based on lookup value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I want to remove the words "FaKe TaBLet" in B2 into a new desired results like in C2, which is 'great number two' using (as far as I know) Reverse partial lookup or other formula instead of using 'Substitute'.

Basically  the words 'FakE TaBLet' in B2 need to be removed based on matching the lookup list in A5 (ruling out the uppercase or lowercase)

I know it can be easily removed by using =SUBSTITUTE formula and I have tried that. The problem is, I have massive lookup list data which are different respectively.

I have tried
=TRIM(LOWER(IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH($A$6:$A$9,B2,1),$A$6:$A$9),""))) based on learning in https://youtu.be/Xts7oC3agMs but apparently that is not applicable if the lookup word are contains more than one word.

Can anyone enlighten on this? any answer would be very appreciated!

thanks a lot

```
 |   A          |         B                    |   C               |
1|              |   *Keyword                   |*Desired result    |
2|              | great FakE TaBLet number two | great number two  |
3|              |                              |                   |
4|              |                              |                   |
5|*lookup list  |                              |                   |
6| Fake         |                              |                   |
7| Fake Tablet  |                              |                   |
8| Fake Tab     |                              |                   |
9| Fake table   |                              |                   |

                     ︙
```

Comment: Col A is labeled as the lookup value but it contains four items.  How do you decide to use Fake Tablet?  Have you looked at the SEARCH function?

Comment: I think the more appropriate term is 'lookup list' instead of 'lookup value'. I have edited it. We decide to use 'fake tablet' based on matching the B2 and lookup list, kind of using SEARCH that referred to B2 and remove it by match it up with lookup list. any idea?

Comment: 1. Is Fake Tablet a hard-coded value in your formula (which would have nothing to do with the contents of Col A), or is it selected from the four available values?  If it is selected, on what basis do you do that? 2. Have you looked at the SEARCH function?  That finds the location of one string inside another (not case sensitive), which you could use to extract whatever came before and after it and concatenate those pieces together, giving you your solution.

Comment: 1. Selected from four available values. Because I have many lookup list words and massive data that I have to build a 'selected lookup list' to match it up 2. Yes, if you look at my original thread, I have tried SEARCH function , but apparently it doesn't work for two or more words lookup list. Please have a look at my original post

Comment: @freakyholic, check I'v posted the lookup solution to replace words as you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula works fine for me (I'm using Excel 2016) to return the string to be removed, including cases where the string to be removed is more than one word. However, since it grabs the last matching item in the lookup list, you'll need to rearrange your lookup list from shortest string to longest string to make sure it gets the longest matching string:

```
*lookup list
Fake
Fake Tab
Fake table
Fake Tablet
```

Once you've made that change, this formula returns the final string:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B2),TRIM(LOWER(IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH($A$6:$A$9,B2,1),$A$6:$A$9),""))),""))
```

That formula returns:

```
great number two
```

This formula does have the limitation that only one string from column A will be found and removed. You can find and remove more by duplicating the formula across more columns, but given that your lookup list is "massive" it probably isn't practical to find them all. If you do want to find and remove all members of a massive lookup list, I would use VBA.